# react native notification background

Tags: javascript

Для пуш уведомления я использовал react-native-push-notification. Но столкнулся с проблемой. Не происходит уведомление в сервисе. Когда приложение закрыто. Как сделать пуш уведомление в фоне на react native?

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно использовать так называемые remote notifications. Смысл в том, что вы у себя на сервере сохраняете токены устройств и позже через api платформы можете присылать уведомления на устройства. Т.е. от приложения требуется только запросить разрешение и отослать токен к вам на сервер.

Просто ищите статьи про то, как настроить пуш. У вас отличается только код приложения, все остальное... сервер, сертификаты и тп тоже самое.
https://habrahabr.ru/post/156811/

Answer (score 0):

В `xcode` откройте `capabilities`, и там в `Background modes` включите `Remote notifications`.